# In unity, if I have millions of colliders that doesn't do anything, should I deactivate them when I don't need them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity, if I have millions of colliders that doesn't do anything, no rigibody, the script attached to them doesn't have anything in update, and I make sure they don't have physics interaction with each other, should I deactivate them when I don't need them?//

The colliders are generated for destructible terrain, so far it seems they don't affect performance, but I am aiming for an open world game, so there should be millions of them.//

When I leave the area, should I deactive the colliders in that area?

Comment: Are you really wondering if you should keep in memory millions of things that do nothing or have I missed something in your question?

Comment: why have these colliders at all then?

Comment: the colliders are generated for destructible terrain, so far it seems they don't affect performance, but I am aiming for an open world game, so there should be millions of them

Comment: You can try to maybe leave a way to control all the colliders for now, then when you feel the need to disable all those colliders (e.g. game's getting big and laggy) you can use the way you prepared. Who knows? Maybe [Unity handles them well](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1344073/will-too-many-colliders-affect-game-performance.html), or maybe you won't even reach that count of colliders in final game. Or if you want to be pre-cautious, why not? You're not using them for the moment anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it is better to do the each `gameObject.SetActive(false);`

Long answer:
However, leave just the collider which has no interaction is not much memory drain.
You can check in unity **profiler** (physics tab) by turning on and off for those colliders on run time.
Those generated terrain may have “segmentation”. If player is on a REGION than turn physics on that REGION only.

<P.S> I think, the main problem for memory may be graphic for generated terrain. That is usually optimized by **occlusion culling**.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a tag like "environment" or a similar identifier that can be referenced in a script to deactivate these objects when you don't want to use them.

Lower end machines trying to run the game could run into issues and its better to not consume resources if you don't need to.

Here is a loose idea:

```
public GameObject environment[];

if(player is within radius of object){
    environment = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("environment");

    foreach (GameObject obj in environment)
        {
            obj.SetActive(false);
        }
}
```